# How to display all posts in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to display all post in my WordPress home page.

I have written following query for getting all post but I do not get all posts. It just displays 10 or 11 posts:

```
 $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => $number,
                'order' => $sort_by,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tag' => $tags,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                );
 $args['tax_query'] =  array(
                    array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                    'field' => 'slug',
                    'terms' => 'post-format-video',
                    ));
 $query = new WP_Query($args);
```

So please let me know how can I get all posts.

Comment: see if [this link](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-display-all-your-wordpress-posts-on-one-page/) helps.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> Displaying all posts that has been published. You have to use **post_per_page='-1'** to retrive all the posts.

```
$args = array(
'post_type'=> 'post',
'orderby'    => 'ID',
'post_status' => 'publish',
'order'    => 'DESC',
'posts_per_page' => -1 // this will retrive all the post that is published 
);
$result = new WP_Query( $args );
if ( $result-> have_posts() ) : ?>
<?php while ( $result->have_posts() ) : $result->the_post(); ?>
<?php the_title(); ?>   
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Hope so this will retrive all the posts as per your expectation.

Comment: i tried this solution but it do no found solution when i use post_per_page='-1' in query still it show me 10 or 11 post not more than 10 or 11

Comment: Check whether you have more than 11 posts under published status. or you post the database table values by editing the question. Since `post_per_page=-1` will definitely override the count

Comment: What's with the constant opening and closing php?

Answer (score 1):

try Multiple loops :

```
<?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>    
    <!-- do stuff ... -->
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

if you need Advanceded query use this :

```
<?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
```

and you can use query_posts() get all posts

Comment: **have a look at the question: How to display all posts in WordPress?.**. What are you answering . Answer relevant to the question. `posts_per_page=10` will get 10 posts alone :)

Comment: thanks "" <?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=10'); ?>  ""
really worked for mee!!! (ofcource it will not show all but still)

Comment: <?php query_posts( 'post_type=post&posts_per_page=10'); ?>
How increment posts_per_page=X by clicks?

Answer (score 1):

#### Watch out: Spelling mistake

**Rookie mistake to watch out for:** remember that it's `HAVE_posts` and NOT `HAS_posts`. I was pulling my hair out for mixing that up as a non-native (`have_posts()`)

- `has_posts()` ❌
- `have_posts()` ✅

---

#### Sample Code

Also, here's a sample code without alternate syntax all the other answers are using:

```php
<?php

$args = [
  "post_type" => "post",
  "orderby" => "ID",
  "post_status" => "publish",
  "order" => "DESC",
  "posts_per_page" => -1, // this will retrive all the post that is published
];

$result = new WP_Query( $args );

if ( $result->have_posts() ) {
  
  while ( $result->have_posts() ) {
    
    $result->the_post(); // change to the post we're currently at in the loop
    
    $post = $result->post; // WP_Post object

    $id = $post->ID;
    $title = $post->post_title;
    $content = $post->post_content;

    // alternatively:

    $title = get_the_title();
    $content = get_the_content();
  }

  wp_reset_postdata(); // reset changing to the other posts
}

?>
```

[WP_Post properties reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#comment-2101)

Answer (score 0):

Set the variable `posts_per_page => -1`

As so:

```
 $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => -1,
                'order' => $sort_by,
                'orderby' => 'title',
                'post_status' => 'publish',
                'tag' => $tags,
                'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
              );
```

This will make Query get all posts in your table.

See more in the [WP Query docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/)